# problem reinstalling nginx on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-18.04, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, serve

I am running on ubuntu server for some reason i uninstalled nginx . and i need to reinstall it

but when i want to reinstall it gives me error

[image]

when i want to install

```
usa@dl:~$ sudo apt-get install nginx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package nginx is a virtual package provided by:
  nginx-light 1.14.0-0ubuntu1
  nginx-full 1.14.0-0ubuntu1
  nginx-extras 1.14.0-0ubuntu1
You should explicitly select one to install.
```

i used the command to uninstall completely but still i can not

any idea

Answer (score 0):

I guess you figured out by now that there is no 'nginx' package available. There might have been one when you first installed it, but now there isn't. You need to install one from the list.

So any of these commands will work:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx-light
sudo apt-get install nginx-full
sudo apt-get install nginx-extras
```